# Google Maps API drops markers individually

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to drop markers individually (with a delay) when loading them from an XML file, but I can't seem to get it working. What am I doing wrong?

Dropping them all at once is working.

This is what I have so far:

```
var map = null;
  function initialize(){
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.899084, 12.486559),
      zoom: 2,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      streetViewControl: false
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    loadXMLFile();
  }

  function loadXMLFile(){
    var filename = 'concerts.xml';
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: filename ,
      dataType: "xml",
      success: parseXML,
      error : onXMLLoadFailed
    });

    function onXMLLoadFailed(){
      alert("An Error has occurred.");
    }

    function parseXML(xml){
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      var counter = 0;
        $(xml).find("resultsPage results event").each(function(){
          //Read the latitude and longitude for each Marker
          var lat = $(this).find('venue').attr('lat');
          var lng = $(this).find('venue').attr('lng');
          if (lat == "") {
            var locLat = $(this).find('location').attr('lat');
            var locLng = $(this).find('location').attr('lng');

            var markerCoords = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(locLat), parseFloat(locLng));
          }else{
            var markerCoords = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat), parseFloat(lng));
          }
          bounds.extend(markerCoords);

          setTimeOut(function () {
            addMarker(markerCoords);
          }, counter * 200);

          //increment counter
          counter++;

        });
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
  }

  function addMarker(markerCoords){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: markerCoords,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: `setTimeOut` -> `setTimeout`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are closing over `markerCoords` in your set timeout, so by the time the function runs it will have changed and it will add multiple markers at the same location.

```
setTimeout(function () {
        addMarker(markerCoords); // markerCoords will change before addMarker called!
}, counter * 200);
```

Your fix is relatively simple, just pass a copy of the `markerCoords`:

```
setTimeout(
    (function(c) { 
        return function() { 
            addMarker(c); 
        } 
    }(markerCoords)), counter++);
```

Comment: Where do i use this final part of the code? do i use it instead of my original part?

Comment: @user2814540 - yeah, sorry for the late reply!